# Transistor latching circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, npn, pnp, latching

I have made the following circuit from a few online sources, it is very basic but uses two NPN transistors to make a latching circuit that toggles when either push button goes to ground.

[My Falstad Circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Av%20-304%20192%20-304%20-32%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0At%20160%2096%20192%2096%200%201%20-1.9898610598480242%200.039955438422059175%20100%0At%20-144%2096%20-176%2096%200%201%200.7196775581247966%200.7596329965458731%20100%0Ar%20-144%2096%20-48%2096%200%2010%0Ar%20160%2096%2064%2096%200%2010%0As%20-144%2096%20-144%20192%200%201%20true%0As%20160%2096%20160%20192%200%201%20true%0Aw%20-144%20192%20160%20192%200%0Ar%20-176%2048%20-176%20-32%200%2010%0Ar%20192%2048%20192%20-32%200%2010%0Aw%20-304%20-32%20-176%20-32%200%0Aw%20-176%20-32%20192%20-32%200%0A162%20-224%2048%20-224%20144%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20160%20192%20192%20192%200%0Aw%20192%2048%20192%2080%200%0Aw%20-224%2048%20-176%2048%200%0Aw%20-176%2048%20-176%2080%200%0Aw%20192%20112%20192%20144%200%0Aw%20-176%20112%20-176%20144%200%0Aw%20-224%20144%20-176%20144%200%0Aw%20-176%20144%20-176%20192%200%0Aw%20192%20144%20192%20192%200%0Aw%20192%2048%20-48%2048%200%0Aw%20-48%2048%20-48%2096%200%0Aw%20-176%2048%20-96%2048%200%0Aw%2064%2096%2064%2016%200%0Aw%20-96%2048%20-96%2016%200%0Aw%20-96%2016%2064%2016%200%0Aw%20-144%20192%20-176%20192%200%0Aw%20-176%20192%20-304%20192%200%0A)

[image: NPN Latching]

My question is, how would I make this work if I wanted both latches to be triggered when going high instead of low.

Would I need to use PNP transistors instead?

Comment: Can you please share an openable link, or better just add a screenshot of your circuit and maybe explain what you are trying to do and where you have problems?

Comment: Hi Niteesh, I tried to use a short URL but stackexchange didn't like it here it is anyway: http://tinyurl.com/y2bwnt97.

Comment: We don't like short URLs - or, indeed, any URLs, really. They have a habit of disappearing and leaving broken and useless questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can just use the same basic circuit but swap the buttons around and add a couple of extra resistors.

This has the arguably slight advantage that the button turns the transistor it's attached to on instead of off, making it a little easier to understand.

But historically, circuits would tend to use active low inputs and connect the switches to ground, especially when using TTL devices which work that way.

Or, as you say, use PNP transistors and flip the circuit vertically.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fShHYL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Amazing! [Updated Falstad Circuit](http://tinyurl.com/y3a4bjhh). Would a PNP design use less resistors?

Comment: Yes, it would just be a mirror image of the original circuit.